# Owl Carousel 2 - Inline background images not working

Tags: owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I just downloaded Owl Carousel 2 to create a carousel with inline background images. I thoroughly read the documentation available at: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/lazyLoad.html

It says:

> LazyLoad HTML strucutre requires class="owl-lazy" and
>   data-src="url_to_img" or/and data-src-retina="url_to_highres_img". If
>   you set above settings not on  but on other DOM element then Owl
>   will load an image into css inline background style.

**Here is my JS initialization:**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    lazyLoad: true,
    margin: 20,
    loop: false,
    nav: false,
    items: 3,
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="owl-lazy" data-src="images/carousel/default/default04.png" data-src-retina="images/carousel/default/default04.png" alt=""></div>
```

But its not loading that image that was injected into the div. I have searched it on google but all in vein. Its not working now, may be an update failure or something. Or may be I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could load it in an `<img>` tag with the following styles:

```
.carousel-image {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Make sure your owl item container has `position: relative;` and the content has a `z-index` greater than 1.